# SASS: Is there a way to add an optional selector?

Tags: css, sass, dart-sass

my idea is to add optionally a CSS-Selector to already existing selector stack inside a mixin.

My wish

```
@mixin myMixin(mobileSelector:true) {
  @if(mobileSelector) {
    .foo .mobile:before,
  }
  .classXY .subclass:before{
    color: red;
  }
}

.awesomeClass-A {
  @include myMixin();
}

@media (min-width: 1025px){
  .awesomeClass-B {
    @include myMixin(false);
  }
}
```

Should compile to:

```
 
.awesomeClass-A .foo .mobile:before,
.awesomeClass-A .classXY .subclass:before {
    color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .awesomeClass-B .classXY .subclass:before {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

How to get this work? :)

Comment: What is `subclass`? It doesn't seem to be a valid selector.

Comment: Correct. Should be ```.subclass``` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a variable and interpolation syntax:

```
@mixin myMixin($mobileSelector: true) {
  $mobile: if($mobileSelector, ".foo .mobile:before,","");
  #{$mobile} .classXY .subclass:before{
    color: red;
  }
}

.awesomeClass-A {
  @include myMixin();
}

@media (min-width: 1025px){
  .awesomeClass-B {
    @include myMixin(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the if-Function in the second line is what I was searching for. :D Great! Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

Just call variables with `$` before and add whole class to `@if` condition:

```
@mixin myMixin($mobileSelector: true) {
  @if ($mobileSelector) {
    .foo .mobile:before,
    .classXY subclass:before {
      color: red;
    }
  } @else {
    .classXY subclass:before {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

.awesomeClass-A {
  @include myMixin();
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .awesomeClass-B {
    @include myMixin(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, this will work, but I wanted to avoid redundant code parts.